# Понимание JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Дайте пожалуйста совет по поводу того, как легче и удобнее всего писать код на js.

С точки зрения синтаксиса я все понимаю, но как дело доходит до написания большого количества функций чтобы создать что то не банальное у меня начинается ступор.

У меня не получается в голове представить ту структуру кода, которая должна быть на выходе. 
Как избегать этого ступора?

Вроде когда вижу готовое решение этой задачи, то там нет ничего сверхъестественного, а сам написать не могу, потому что туплю)

Comment: открываете гит любого крупного приложения и смотрите на архитектуру, что-то из этого подчеркнёте

Answer (score 12, accepted):

У меня было точно также когда я только начинал много лет назад. Периодически ступор возникает и сейчас, в этом нет ничего плохого, все-таки мы люди, а не машины.

Но посоветовать я вам могу:

- Делите задачу на простые и понятные части, и реализуйте их по-отдельности, "забывая" о других частях (Декомпозиция).
- Рисуйте схемы и диаграммы на листочке (Да, карандашом. Так, как вам удобно и понятно, но лучше использовать классические обозначения - квадратики, ромбики, UML).
- Не усложняйте там, где это не нужно на данный момент (не надо ломать голову над оптимизацией, лучше сначала добраться до финиша. Со временем и опытом все придет).
- Если совсем тупняк, то отвлекитесь, погуляйте например, чтобы проветрить мозги 
  )
- Если вы пытаетесь, но все равно, "что-то идет не так", то тут (на SO) всегда есть люди, которые помогут (или отругают, но бережно)

А по-поводу js, то рекомендую пройти онлайн курс от простого к сложному. Например вот этот [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/)*

- Сам по нему учусь. А что делать! )

Answer (score 1):

Учите design pattern (паттерн проектирования). Иногда можно их комбинировать.

Основные паттерны:

1. Модуль
2. Открытый модуль
3. Синглтон
4. Фабрика